# Confusing regarding final year modules

Tags: advice

My university has released the modules that I am available to take next year in my final year of undergrad. A PDF was also provided grouping the modules into their respective mathematical topics.

I'll be the first to admit I'm a little in over my head here and it is a little daunting that I am to choose by Monday despite knowing nothing about the prospective courses (the titles and short descriptions are not very telling). I was thinking of taking all of the probability and statistics modules that are offered as well as coding theory and cryptography. Would this set me up well for a future career? Any advice/help is more than welcome, thanks.

Comment: This doesn't answer your question, but do you have access to lecture notes on the internet? Perhaps skimming through them briefly would give you an idea about if you want to take certain courses.

Comment: Unfortunately not, I tried to take a look but no success.

Comment: I'd say that coding theory and cryptography are good , if you find time you should learn a language like python or java. If you want better advice id suggest talking to a senior or your professor .

Comment: If I understand well you are an university student in your final year. Do you know if you've an academic tutor? That is, in some universtities the students have a corresponding academic tutor (a professor that solves certain doubts about the programs of courses and can provide some information for the students), even if maybe the students don't know that they have such available information. Maybe you should ask in the Secretary of the Department of Mathematics if you've an academic tutor to solve the doubts in your career.